# Does a foreign company need to be HIPAA compliant to work with a covered entity?

Tags: united-states, international, hipaa

If I'm a HIPAA covered entity and I want to work with a foreign company (e.g. the foreign company would provide the covered entity with PHI from US and other people), does that foreign company also have to be HIPAA compliant?